# Zbrush Displacement export problem

Tags: 3d

When i export the displacement map without smooth uvs it generates this kind of low poly bake artifact, please If someone knows what is happening let me know, thanks[image]

Comment: Smooth UVs handles rendering artifacts like this. Why are you turning it off?